# any experts of Windows Media Service

Tags: windows, flash, service, streaming, media

anyone know whether Windows Media Service supports streaming flv on Windows Server 2003? I tried but failed to find any claim documents.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/server.aspx

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortnately, Windows Media Services doesn't seem to stream FLVs:

> A server running Windows Media
>   Services 9 Series can stream the
>   following file types:
>
> - Windows Media Audio (WMA)
> - Windows Media Video (WMV)
> - Advanced System Format (ASF)
> - MP3
> - Windows Media playlist (WSX)
>
> Source : [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/faq.aspx#2_4)

The most common solutions are :

> - Flash Media Server (formerly called Flash Communication Server)
> - Red5 server (OPEN SOURCE)
> - Wowza Pro
> - VCS
> - ElectroServer
> - WebORB for .NET
>
> Source : [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video)

Comment: Hi Theo.T, I have read the documents you mentioned. FLV file types are not in the list explicitly (it also does not have a list of non-supported fiel type list), does it mean FLV streaming is not supported? Thanks.

Comment: Another question is, seems on Windows Media Service, there is no bit rate throttling control settings by file types, for example, I think if I could set by extension type to set flv bit rate to the same as the content encoded bit rate it would be ok.

Comment: Hello, indeed the FLVs are not supported. 
When you have questions that are not related (as the 2nd one) you should open new questions so other users could take advantage of the answers. (I don't know the answer BTW)

Comment: Thanks Theo.T, I will mark your answer for my original question as answered and start a new thread to discuss new questions. :-)

Comment: I posted here, if you are interested, we could discuss there.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680204/throttling-control-in-windows-media-service