# throttling control in Windows Media Service

Tags: windows, flash, service, media, throttling

I am wondering whether on Windows Server 2003, in Windows Media Service, we could setup/configure throttling settings for any file types (even the file types not supported by streaming by Windows Media Service), for example, setup .flv file download/streaming throttling bit rate to 100k or setup the bitrate throttling control to the same as encoded bit rate.

I have searched Windows Media Service manual for a long time, but can not find this feature exlpicitly documented.

BTW: I am just curious what is the behavior of Windows Media Service if we put unsupported streaming file types, like .flv flies.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

[I thought that Windows Media Services supported only a subset of file types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Services) (and flv is not one of them).
If you want throttling control for flv you will need [Flash Streaming Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediastreaming/) or [Apache with the throttling mod](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_throttle) or [IIS 7 with the throttling module.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/03/18/iis-7-0-bit-rate-throttling-module-released.aspx)

Comment: @Shay, 1. from your wikipedia link about Windows Media Service, where claims "Windows Media Services supported only a subset of file types."? 2. I think you mean Windows Media Service supports a small set type of media, and for such types of supported media, streaming and throttling (continued)

Comment: are both supported, but for non-supported media types, no throttling and streaming are supported. My understanding of your points correct? Thanks.

Comment: @George2, yes current WMS cannot stream or throttle unsupported type.

Comment: @Shay, how about your answer to this item -- 1. from your wikipedia link about Windows Media Service, where claims "Windows Media Services supported only a subset of file types."? :-)

Comment: @George2, sorry I don't understand the question.